# Javascript Error (IE): Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **2015 Note:** Everyone should go look through their old questions and be encouraged by how far they've come. There are so many things wrong with this code – it's wonderful.

This code works PERFECTLY in Firefox, and in IE the line ending 'negative'); breaks. I have no idea how to fix it! Argghhh!

```
$(".topline strong").digits().each(function () {
    s = $(this),
    c = "change";
    if ($(s).hasClass(c) & $(s).text().replace(/%/gi, "") > 0) {
        $(s).addClass("positive");
    }
    if ($(s).hasClass(c) & $(s).text().trim().charAt(0) == "-") $(s).addClass("negative");
});
```

Comment: Can you separate the statements to see which one causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please use `&&` instead of `&` (unless it's meant for minimizing)
2. `String.trim` isn't widely implemented yet. Use

   ```
   $(s).hasClass(c) && /^\s*-/.test($(s).text())
   ```

   instead.

I'd rather rewrite the code as:

```
$(".topline strong").digits().each(function() {
  var s = $(this);
  if (s.hasClass("change")) { // no need to $() an already $()-ed object.
    var value = parseFloat(s.text());
    if (value != 0)
      s.addClass(value > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting - though I did try &&. JSLint didn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.trim()` you can use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) like this:

```
$(".topline strong").digits().each(function () {
  var s = $(this), c = "change";
  if (s.hasClass(c) && s.text().replace(/%/gi, "") > 0) { s.addClass("positive"); }
  if (s.hasClass(c) && $.trim(s.text()).charAt(0) == "-") s.addClass("negative");
});
```

Also note the `s` changes, there's no need to clone it as another jQuery object each time, it already is one so use it :)  As for the error: `.trim()` isn't in all browsers, this is why jQuery includes the [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function (same reason it has [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), IE doesn't have `.indexOf()`).

Also when declaring variable use `var`, otherwise you're creating *global* variables.

---

As an aside for future readers of this, jQuery 1.4.3+ [will use](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L575) the [native String.prototype.trim](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L58) if it's available when calling [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).